# Discord.js bot manual reply by creator PM. Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Right now, my bot logs PM sent to it to me, via PM. Then i write an answer on the cmd. (Code1)

So, the question is, it's possible to make my discord.js bot, after logging the message on my PM, reply to the original user with a message I send to my bot on the PM? That's what I tried (Code2)

would be something like:

> RandomUser to the bot: Who are you and why you talk to me?

> Bot to me: [RandomUser] Who are you and why you talk to me?

> Me to the bot: I'm a bot from server X and i'm talking to you because Y

> Bot to RandomUser: I'm a bot from server X and i'm talking to you because Y

I hope you get it :(

Also would be cool to know how to do to make my bot wait till I answer. Because it happened to my many times that 2 users talk to the bot then when I answer the 1st message it sends the same message to the 1st user but 2 times.
Sorry for asking for that sort of weird and maybe stupid things.

Code1

```
console.log(`[${message.author.username}] ${message.content}`);

const rl = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout
});


rl.question(`Answer to ${message.author.username}: `, (answer) => {
   message.author.send(`${answer}`)
     .then(function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
        //console.error(data);
     });

  rl.close();
});
```

Code2

```
if (message.author.id !== autorUser.id) {
      var prevUser = message.author;
      autorUser.send(`${message.author.username} a [${botUser.username}]: ${message.content}`)
        .then(message => {
          const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1 });
          console.log(collector)
          collector.on('collect', message => {
            if (message.author.id === autorUser.id) {
              prevUser.send(`${message.content}`);
            }
          });
        }
        )
        .catch()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the RandomUser's ID and create a special command (or whatever) for replying.

**For Example:**

> RandomUser to the bot: Who are you and why you talk to me?

> Bot to me: [RandomUser **ID**] Who are you and why you talk to me?

> Me to the bot: (for example) !reply **ID** I'm a bot from server X and i'm talking to you because Y

> Bot to RandomUser: I'm a bot from server X and i'm talking to you because Y

Fetch the user's ID and send a message to them.

**If you're using v12 of DiscordJS:**

```js
client.users.fetch("ID").then(user => user.send("some message"));
```

or

```js
client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === "ID").send("some message");
```

**If you're using older version of DiscordJS:**

```js
client.users.find(user => user.id === "ID").send("some message");
```